# Define an array that can not contain null in Swagger 2.0

Tags: swagger-2.0

```
    required:
          - property_1
        properties:
          property_1:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
```

In this way **property_1 = null** not accept, but I need a way to property_1 not allow for [null,null,"string_1"]
in Swagger 2.0

Answer (score 3):

Your definition is correct. Swagger 2.0 does not support `null` values in payloads.

Comment: Is there any way to check null values in the items? It means I want to add array items as required values.

Comment: If you mean the array must contain at least N items, add `minItems: ...` to your array schema.

Comment: If you mean you want the server to accept `["foo", "bar"]` but reject `[null,null,"string_1"]` - some server-side framework automatically validate payloads against OpenAPI schema.